# Issue with div padding?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I have created a div. In div tag I have written some text boxes and radio buttons. Now the div contents are very close to div margin But I need some space at left side and right side. I need to start and end the div contents between yellow marks. The blue marks are div margins.

[image]

Div CSS:

```
.docsDiv
{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: #C0C0C0 groove 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="docsDiv">
  <p> Gender</p>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender_1" />
  <label for="gender_1">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender_2" />
  <label for="gender_2">Female</label>

    Father's Name   
    <input type="text" name="fatherName" id="fatherName">   

    Mother's Name
    <input type="text"  name="motherName" id="motherName">  

    Date of Birth
    <input type="text" id="dateofbirth">        
</div>
```

Comment: Just make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) might help us

Comment: Why not just add padding to the container:   padding: 0 5px; ?

Comment: If you add padding the box would be 100% + paddings wide. To avoid that add `box-sizing: border-box;` to your `.docsDiv`. Or... better simply add your padding and remove `width: 100%;` - `div`s are block elements so will stretch to whole available width.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/manjunath_r/vrsy0per/ This is fiddle link

Comment: If you don't want your `div`s to have space on the sides just add negative margin to those elements equal to `div` padding. E.g. `.docsDiv { padding: 0 1em; }` and `.docsDiv input { margin: 0 -1em; }`

Comment: Than you @ norin89 it is working now

Comment: IE versions 9 and below don't like negative margins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dar93mks/) You can add a div inside the wrapper (`docsDiv`) with padding to push other elements inward.

```
<div class="docsDiv">
    <div class="padding-20">
        <p> Gender</p>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender_1" />
        <label for="gender_1">Male</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender_2" />
        <label for="gender_2">Female</label>

        Father's Name   
        <input type="text" name="fatherName" id="fatherName">   

        Mother's Name
        <input type="text"  name="motherName" id="motherName">  

        Date of Birth
        <input type="text" id="dateofbirth">
    </div>      
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.padding-20 {
     padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
.docsDiv
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 15px; **/*Changed*/**
    box-sizing:border-box; **/*Added*/**
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: #C0C0C0 groove 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vrsy0per/3/)**

Comment: If I add that right side is not showing properly it is going out of screen. http://jsfiddle.net/manjunath_r/vrsy0per/1/

Comment: Should read the full answer you have to add `box-sizing:border-box;` try now

Comment: If any issue get back to me